# Is it possible to map the bits in a char to arbitrary bits in a short?

Tags: c, mapping, microcontroller

I was wondering if there is any way to arbitrarily map the bits of a smaller variable to the bits in a larger variable. I think my question will be easier to understand with an example.

If I have a 16 bit register "PORTA", and then I have a 8 bit variable OPT1, I want to be able to write

```
PORTA = 0x0000
OPT1 = 0xAB
```

And end up with PORTA containing 0x0A0B.

The bits would automatically be mapped as followed just by writing to the variable OPT1

```
OPT1_bit0 => PORTA_bit0
OPT1_bit1 => PORTA_bit1
OPT1_bit2 => PORTA_bit2
OPT1_bit3 => PORTA_bit3

OPT1_bit4 => PORTA_bit8
OPT1_bit5 => PORTA_bit9
OPT1_bit6 => PORTA_bit10
OPT1_bit7 => PORTA_bit11
```

Comment: Using a union.  After fiddling with alignment, that should work.

Comment: It's not possible to automate this, you have to create a function that does this by extracting the bits you want and put them where you want.

Comment: @Adam - I assume you ment `OPT1_bit4 => PORTA_bit8`, etc. Otherwise your `0xAB => 0x0A0B` is not correct.

Comment: any fancy language tricks you do at this level will result in masks and shifts anyway, you should avoid any fancy language tricks and just do the masks and shifts.  more reliable and maintainable, same performance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can **directly** map the assignment, meaning:

```
OPT1 = 0xAB => PORTA = 0x0A0B
```

However you can automate the job via macro. Ex:

```
static int PORTA = 0x0000;
#define OPT1(val) (PORTA = (val&0x0F)|((val&0xF0)<<4))
```

So now when you make an "assignment" to OPT1 it will move itself correctly into PORTA for you every time:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  OPT1(0xAB);
  printf("PORTA's value: %#x\n", PORTA);
  return 0;
}

mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
PORTA's value: 0xa0b
```